# Gradle file push to github repository

Tags: android, git, github

I was pushing my Android application project to my github repository. I saw two folder .gradle and gradle were not pushed but another folder called gradle/wrapper instead got pushed. I am not sure where this gradle/wrapper folder came from and if this is a normal thing that happens when pushing an Android app.

Edit: I closely inspected a bit more and the gradle folder that I was talking about is the gradle/wrapper folder. It is just that I didn't expand that folder initially.  The .gradle folder is still not showing up in my Github repository though.

Comment: that because that folder is generated at build time like build folders

Answer (score 2):

The `.gradle` folder should not be committed and should be included as part of the gitignore

https://www.gitignore.io/api/android,androidstudio

This is the directory used by the wrapper on your local machine to store the downloaded Gradle dependencies (as compared to installing Gradle separately yourself and configuring the IDE to use that)

`build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` should be the least amount of required files for any Gradle project, the wrapper is optional but recommended to standardize the version of Gradle used to build the project

Answer (score 0):

if you don't see a file that you have pushed via git, please check your .gitignore file.

Gradle/wrapper folder is generated upon building.